# Equidistant partition of a side in a convex pentagon

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCDE$ be a convex pentagon with equal angles $AEB$ = $BEC$ = $CED$. Also, let angles $BAE$ = $CBE$ = $DCE$ be equal. Let P be the intersection of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$.

Prove that line $EP$ runs through the center of the side $BC$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From $\triangle EAB \sim \triangle EBC \sim \triangle ECD$ and $\angle ABC = \angle BCD$, prove $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle BCD$.

From this, prove $\triangle ABG \sim \triangle BCH$ and $\triangle EAG \sim \triangle EBH$.

Then $CH/EH = BG/EG$.

Comment: I saw but could bot prove $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle BCD$. Thus I used Ceva´s theorem |ER|/|RB| ∙|BM|/|MC| ∙|CN|/|NE| =1 and from there took to prove |ER|/|RB| ∙|CN|/|NE| =1 by using similarity of $EBCD$ and $EABC$ and from that |BD|/|EC| =|AC|/|EB|  and then claiming |ER|/|RB| =|NE|/|CN|  .
Your approach is far more elegant. Perhaps you can help me how to prove $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle BCD$? Thanks.

Comment: Writing out the ratios for the three triangles,
$$\hspace{3px} \frac {EA} {EB} = \frac {AB} {BC} = \frac {BE} {CE} \,, \\
\hspace{15px} \frac {EB} {EC} = \frac {BC} {CD} = \frac {CE} {DE} \Rightarrow \\
\frac {AB} {BC} = \frac {BC} {CD}\,.$$
Now the SAS similarity criterion applies.